# Expect script for copying file

Tags: shell-script, scripting, expect

I am trying to move/copy some files from my local machine to another host which I am able to access via ssh. But unfortunately this below script is not working.

when I run this script it is asking me `Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?` every time I run it.

I have 3 file file on my local machine `ranfull` `ranhalf` `midran` which I need to transfer/copy it to other host via scp script, but only the first file is getting copied.

It won't be possible to set `sshkeygen`.

```
#!/bin/bash

HOSTS="VM2 VM3 VM4 VM1"

read -p "Password: " PASSWORD

for HOST in $HOSTS
do
expect -c "
spawn /usr/bin/scp /tmp/ranfull ranhalf midran root@$HOST:/tmp/
expect {
"*password:*" { send $PASSWORD\r;interact }
}
exit
"
done
```

Comment: Where are the files `ranhalf` and `midran`? In `/tmp`?

Comment: all are in the same location `/tmp`.

Comment: `spawn /usr/bin/scp /tmp/ranfull ranhalf midran root@$HOST:/tmp/` should be `spawn /usr/bin/scp -v /tmp/ranfull /tmp/ranhalf /tmp/midran root@$HOST:/tmp/`

Comment: @SHW I changed worked but i am getting this error, I don't know why `The authenticity of host VM3 (192.168.0.119)' can't be established`. & every time it is waiting for `Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?` caan i skip this message

Comment: Are you changing the IP of either source or target machine ?

Comment: Add `-o StrictHostKeyChecking=no` to the scp command to avoid the error and its prompt, if you are sure it is reasonable for the remote to be changing its host key.

Comment: can I do ssh and pull information of `cat /etc/iscsi/initiatorname.iscsi` via this above script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, your quoting is suspect: you have double quotes in a double quoted string. Let's fix that, and improve the indentation:

```
for HOST in $HOSTS; do
    expect -c <<END_EXPECT
        spawn /usr/bin/scp /tmp/ranfull ranhalf midran root@$HOST:/tmp/
        expect {
            "*password:*" {
                send $PASSWORD\r
                interact
            }
        }
        exit
END_EXPECT
done
```

Now, to accomodate a prompt that may or may not appear, with expect you do this:

```
        expect {
            "Are you sure you want to continue connecting*" {
                send yes\r
                exp_continue
            }
            "*password:*" {
                send $PASSWORD\r
                interact
            }
        }
```

`exp_continue` essentially "loops" back to the expect command so it can still watch for another "Are you sure..." prompt or the password prompt.

Answer (score 1):

**-o StrictHostKeyChecking=no**

`#!/bin/bash
HOSTS="VM2 VM3 VM4 VM1"
read -p "Password: " PASSWORD
for HOST in $HOSTS
do
expect -c "
spawn /usr/bin/scp -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no /tmp/ranfull ranhalf midran root@$HOST:/tmp/
expect {
"password:" { send $PASSWORD\r;interact }
}
exit
"
done`